# Associated file type not working on CLion

Tags: linux, qt, clion, jetbrains-ide, archlinux

I am doing a QT application with CLion IDE, following [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#edit-ui) I selected the option "Open in associated application" but when I try to open my `.ui` file, it prompts to download the file even though if I open it with my file explorer it gets opened by QT Creator.

I guess this is not actually a bug, but a misconfiguration by my side.

How does it determine which is the associated application? And if you know how to set an app as default for my machine it would be nice, if not I'll have to search about how to change it in my specific system.

System information:

- OS: ArchLinux with Liquorix Kernel
- File manager: PCManFM